# dictGetString fails on DDL created dictionary in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

Attempting to follow the [instructions](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries/external-dictionaries/external-dicts-dict-sources/#dicts-external_dicts_dict_sources-clickhouse) for creating a dictionary using DDL:

```sql
-- source table
create table brands (
    id UInt64,
    brand String
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(id)
partition by tuple()
order by id;

-- some data
insert into brands values (1, 'cool'), (2, 'neat'), (3, 'fun');

-- dictionary references source table
CREATE DICTIONARY IF NOT EXISTS brand_dict (
    id UInt64,
    brand String
)
PRIMARY KEY id
SOURCE(CLICKHOUSE(
    host 'localhost'
    port 9000
    user 'default'
    password ''
    db 'default'
    table 'brands'
))
LIFETIME(MIN 1 MAX 10)
LAYOUT(FLAT())

-- looks good:
show dictionaries;


-- no work
-- Code: 36. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: external dictionary 'brand_dict' not found.
select dictGetString('brand_dict', 'id', toUInt64(1));
```

Gives `DB::Exception: external dictionary 'brand_dict' not found.`

I haven't tried with XML config yet, so not sure if it's DDL specific, or if there's something I'm doing wrong there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

such dictionaries require database specified

dictGetString('**DATABASE**.brand_dict'

---

UPD: Starting from 21.4 Functions dictGet, dictHas use current database name if it is not specified for dictionaries created with DDL

Comment: Nice. this works:

`select dictGetString('default.brand_dict', 'brand', toUInt64(1));`